# Clever way to add "and* when I concatenate two string variable that may be empty

Tags: c#

I have a code doing this :

```
if (isNewName())
    name = "newName";
if (isNewLove())
    love = "newLove";

//Generate output message
if (isNewName() && isNewLove)
    result = "Name and Love are updated"
else if (isNewName())
    result = "Name is updated";
else if (isNewLove())
    result = "Love is updated";
```

I was wondering if there is a little trick that would let me generate the result message in one line, or in a more beautiful way.

NB. I'm aware that it is completely useless, that it might affect readability,I'm not looking for a good practice but just for the best trick to make this with as less line as possible.

Comment: i think, that  your code is fine now, but you can incapsulate it into method for simple reusing

Comment: @Frank59 Please read the NB. section ;)

Comment: I saw people downvote the question or ask for it to be closed. I think it match the "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" of the posting rules. Please let me know if I should improve my question & sorry for bad english

Comment: @IggY Well, in general, we don't do "clever" ways to do stuff here. You already have something that works fine - that's a better fit for CodeReview than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @IggY: I second Luaan. This is a waste of time :)

Comment: This question, as it is written, would not be a good fit for Code Review as it seems to be example code. With real context though, CR would be a good fit for this kind of question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string.Join(" and ", new []{ name, love }.Where(i => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i)))
```

Of course, it would be a bit clunky to do this all the time, so you would want to turn this into an extension method:

```
public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> @this, string separator)
{
  return string.Join(separator, @this.Where(i => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i)));
}
```

Which you can then use as e.g.:

```
new  []{ name, love }.Join(" and ");
```

**EDIT:**

For the second part of your question (using `is` when there's only one choice and `are` when there's multiple), you can use e.g. this:

```
public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> @this, string separator, 
  string singleFormat, string multipleFormat)
{
  var nonEmpty = @this.Where(i => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i)).ToArray();

  return string.Format
    (
      nonEmpty.Count == 1 ? singleFormat : multipleFormat, 
      string.Join(separator, nonEmpty)
    );
}
```

Called as:

```
new [] { name, love }.Join(" and ", "{0} is updated", "{1} are updated");
```

Comment: I dont think this is correct. there is the case of is and are too.

Comment: @naveen True, although the OP did ask for just the joining and not the is/are. It can be complicated in many more ways, of course. I've got similar code that also handles stuff like inflection and such.

Comment: Technically, though the title says "and" he did ask for a way to generate the result in one line or "a more beautiful way".

Comment: and it involves checking conditions. i cant for see any tricks too :) chuck norris may find an answer. +1 anyway

Comment: @naveen That's just a tiny part - you can solve that with a simple helper function, or just by using better data types :)

Answer (score 0):

My two cents. Couldn't resist.

```
var names = new List<string>(); 
if (isNewName())
    names.Add("Name");
if (isNewLove())
    names.Add("Love");
var op = String.Format("{0} {1} updated.", String.Join(" and ", names), names.Count == 1 ? "is" : "are");
```

Answer (score -1):

I used `N()` for `IsNewName()` and `L()` for `IsNewLove()` then you could go:

```
result = N()? "Name" : ""
       + (N()&&L())? " and " : "" 
       + L()? "Love" : ""
       + (N()&&L())? " are " : " is "
       + "updated";
```

This is one line, broken down to fit in an answer.

Not useful, as requested.

Comment: Oh, if only I haven't seen code like this (and worse) in real life, it would be funny :D